# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. PHP Site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a PHP / apache site with the following .htacess file and for whatever the reason I am consistently getting the following error in the logs:

AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

**.htaccess file**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.htm|\.php|\.html|/[^.]*)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA]
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Where is your htaccess file and what URL are you going to?

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the root folder.
Not sure what you mean by where the URL is going to?

Comment: What URL are you hitting in order to generate the 500 internal server error? Or is it any URL? In your document root, do you have an index.php file?

Comment: The site still loads, however, the log is capturing this error even though the site is loading as expected. And to answer your question, yes I have an index.php file.

Comment: I think there's something else that may be causing it then, and not the rewrite rule you posted

Comment: Enable `RewriteLog` with `RewriteLogLevel 9` and post what it displays when the infinite loop happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.htm|\.php|\.html|/[^.]*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Have a try.